# Regex / Replace the same string in a text file with predefined values from a dictionary

Tags: regex, text, replace

I have a huge text file with contents similar to this:

```
<!-- $var = aaa -->
<!-- $var = aaa -->
<!-- $var = aaa -->
<!-- $var = aaa -->
<!-- $var = aaa -->
.
<!-- $var = bbb -->
<!-- $var = bbb -->
<!-- $var = bbb -->
<!-- $var = bbb -->
<!-- $var = bbb -->
```

I want to achieve that the `$var` will be replaced like this:

```
<!-- $address = aaa -->
<!-- $city    = aaa -->
<!-- $zip     = aaa -->
<!-- $phone   = aaa -->
<!-- $geo     = aaa -->
.
.
<!-- $address = bbb -->
<!-- $city    = bbb -->
<!-- $zip     = bbb -->
<!-- $phone   = bbb -->
<!-- $geo     = bbb -->
```

The sequence is always the same.
I have researched for about 3 hours, but I can't get past this brain hurdle.
My idea was to realize this with regex, but it seems I need a script to wrestle with this.

Can you give me a hint into which direction to go and is this possible with Regex at all? I'm a beginner, so please be gentle :)

Kind regards
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* write a regular expression to do this in one foul swoop, but it would be way easier to use something like `sed`, which will target lines individually.

```
#!/bin/sh
sed '
  s/\$var/\$address/  # replace $var with $address
  N                   # next line
  s/\$var/\$city   /  # replace $var with $city
  N                   # next line
  s/\$var/\$zip    /  # replace $var with $zip
  N                   # next line
  s/\$var/\$phone  /  # replace $var with $phone
  N                   # next line
  s/\$var/\$geo    /  # replace $var with $geo
' $1
```

You can then run this script against your file.

Comment: Ooh. I need to try that out. Sed is very tempting!

Comment: Thanks. Sed is very powerful and it solved this problem. Additionally I can reuse the code for more files that need processing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a simple way to loop this script until the end of the file is reached?

Comment: It should do that automatically: mine did, when I tested this. Is yours only targeting the first five lines? I'm not a `sed` expert, so I'm afraid I don't know: Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html), or ask another SO question, tagged with `sed`, so someone who knows it better can respond... Sorry I can't be more help :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle one row at a time, applying a different regexp depending on which row it is, as in (I do not know which language you need so see this as pseudocode, and it can be optimized if needed)

```
var replacements = new[]{"address","city","zip","phone","geo"};
var replacement = replacements[row % 5];
var r = new Regex("(^<!-- \$)var(.*$)";
var newline = r.Replace(oldline, "$1"+replacement+"$2");
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm sure I can use it again sometime!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  I have tested this using Progammer's Notepad.  If you are using something different then you may need to tweek it.

```
Find:
(<!-- \$var = (\w+) -->\r\n){5}

Replace:
<!-- $address = \2 -->\r\n<!-- $city    = \2 -->\r\n<!-- $zip     = \2 -->\r\n<!-- $phone   = \2 -->\r\n<!-- $geo     = \2 -->\r\n
```

The key to understanding this is the `\2`.  This references the second group found by the regex.  A group is something trapped in parenthsis `()`.

`\0` would match the entire string.
`\1` would match the first set of backets. `(<!-- \$var = (\w+) -->\r\n)`
`\2` would match the second set of backets. `(\w+)`  This is your aaa or bbb